# Bluetooth API in Chrome for Android Beta

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, bluetooth

Does Chrome for Android Beta have a bluetooth (javascript) API? Google reports that Chrome Beta and Dev channels have the bluetooth api [1] but I cannot call it on Android and Desktop versions of Chrome Beta.

I check for the api by evaluating chrome.bluetooth:

```
if(!chrome.bluetooth) {
   logError('bluetooth api not found');
   return;
}
```

Is there any way (programmatically, or other) to check what apis are supported in a particular Chrome version? `console.log(JSON.stringify(chrome))` doesn't do it.

[1] https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: It appears the API are only available to Chrome Packaged Apps and Extensions. Furthermore, an API is only exposed if listed in the manifest.json file. In other words, there appears to be no easy way to programmatically list the API available.

Answer (score 0):

An experimental [Web Bluetooth API](http://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/) is being added as we speak (not literally of course) in Chrome Dev for Android.

Check out https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web to learn more about it.